# Relationship between reflexive space and separable space

Tags: functional-analysis, hahn-banach-theorem, reflexive-space

If $X$ is reflexive and the dual $X'$ contains a countable set which separates the points of $X$, show $X'$ is separable.

One way to prove this is using the fact that the unit ball $B_{X}$ is a weakly compact set whenever $X$ is reflexive, and since $X'$ has a countable set that separates the points of $X$, the weak topology on $B_{X}$ is metrizable, from which it follows that $X'$ is separable. But I can't use this idea because the notion of weak topology is discussed later in next chapter of my textbook, so I think using Hahn-Banach theorem is the right way to go but I have no idea how to start. Any hint is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
It's enough to prove that $X$ is separable.
Let, $S=\{f_n\}$ be countable collection of functionals which separates points of $X.$

Prove that, there exists $x_n$ such that, $X=\text{span} \{x_n\}\bigoplus \ker f_n.$
Call, $T= \{x_n\}$

Take, $D=\{\lambda x:\lambda\in\mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q} ,x\in T\}$ and show that, $\bar{D}=X$

Edit(Elaborated):
It's well known that, if $Y$ is a n.l.s such that $Y^*$ is separable then $Y$ is separable.

Since, we have shown above that $X$ is separable and $X$ being reflexive , so $X^{**}$ is also separable.

Therefore, $X^*$ is separable.

Comment: @limber is it fine to you?

Comment: Thanks for your hint. I think I get it, but not totally. Why is $X = \text{span}\{x_{n}\} \oplus \ker f_{n}$? Is this a consequence of the reflexivity of $X$ or the Hahn-Banach theorem?

Comment: It's simple linear algebra. $f_n$ is a linear functional. Then , what's the dimension of $X/\ker f_n?$

Comment: OK. By the first isomorphism theorem I know that $X/\ker f_{n} \cong \text{Im } f_{n}$, so $\dim X/\ker f_{n} = 1$. But where is the reflexivity of $X$ needed?

Comment: For a reflexive space $X$ is separable iff $X^*$ is separable.I have edited my answer , check it @limber